# SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Esta é a minha class de conexão:

/**
 * Conn.class [ CONEXÃO ]
 * Classe abstrata de conexão. Padrão SingleTon.
 * Retorna um objeto PDO pelo método estático getConn();
 * 
 * @copyright (c) 2017, Horácio Pedro CONEXÕES INFINITO
 */
abstract class Conn {

```
private static $Host = HOST;
private static $User = USER;
private static $Pass = PASS;
private static $Dbsa = DBSA;

/** @var PDO */
private static $Connect = null;

/**
 * Conecta com o banco de dados com o pattern singleton.
 * Retorna um objeto PDO!
 */
private static function Conectar() {
    try {
        if (self::$Connect == null):
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$Host . ';dbname=' . self::$Dbsa;
            $options = [ PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'];
            self::$Connect = new PDO($dsn, self::$User, self::$Pass, $options);
        endif;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        PHPErro($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
        die;
    }

    self::$Connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return self::$Connect;
}

/** Retorna um objeto PDO Singleton Pattern. */
protected static function getConn() {
    return self::Conectar();
}
```

}

O site estava a funcionar na normalidade, depois de quase 30 dias surgiu-me isto: > SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tem alguma solução viável para este tipo de situação? Qual será a causa por trás disto?

Comment: Provavelmente a causa é possuir muitas conexões com o banco, tal como o erro fala. Para mais detalhes, você precisará descrever, **na pergunta** ([edit]), qual é a estrutura da sua aplicação, colocar os códigos referentes ao problema, descrever a arquitetura do seu servidor, etc.

Comment: Tive o mesmo erro numa outra tecnologia, eu apenas revisei o código e tinha uma conexão sendo aberta, mas a mesma não era fechada, apenas fechei e não aconteceu mais esse erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode revisar seu código e tentar isolar ele melhor e subclasses, dessa forma você vai controlar melhor a chamada das conexões. Tente não fazer várias chamadas em um mesmo método. Se mesmo dividindo melhor o código o erro continuar você pode aumentar o numero de conexões simultâneas nas configurações do MySQL.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, graças a ideia que me deste para revisar as configurações do MySQL que eu pude perceber que o problema não estava no meu código mas sim no MySQLServer do alojamento web.